# Fix resolution on Ubuntu 12.04 (1440x900)

Tags: resolution

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I'm trying to get the correct resolution on my monitor.  I have Ubuntu 12.04 so it has xorg 7.5 which is not supported by ATI anymore for my ATI Radeon Xpress 200 graphics as far as I can tell.  I was told to go to the software center and download ATI binary X.Org driver, so I did that and it gave me a couple more resolution options, but none of them are the correct 1440x900 resolution of my monitor.  Is there any way to get the correct resolution to show up?!

Answer (score 4):

Xorg works with the blob driver and the ATI OSS driver.

To list your available resolutions check xrandr.

[image]

Your maximum resolution is determined by the card, not the monitor.

This screenshot is from 12.04

Comment: so why doesn't the correct resolution show up? It only shows 1360x768 1152x864 1024x768 800x600 and a few lower ones.  1360x768 is the only widescreen one, but it looks way off my monitor.

Comment: Video card limitation.  From the spec sheet you max at 2536(dual) divide by 2 and you're at about 1360  http://www.amd.com/uk/products/notebook/chipsets/radeon-xpress-200M/Pages/ati-radeon-express-200m-amd-specs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by entering the xrandr values manually and adding it to xprofile , for the user.

http://gayanhewa.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/fixing-resolution-on-ubuntu-12-04-for-atiradeon-driver-issues/